# LINQ: How to exclude data columns from DataTable.ItemArray query?

Tags: wpf, linq, gridview, telerik

Given a collection of data rows, IEnumerable of type DataRow, how can I query the collection so as to compute the Sum all the values in the collection (i.e. all the values of all the columns in all the rows) with the exception of two specific columns? I know only two columns prior to run time and those are the two I want to exclude.  All the others I want included in the sum.

There is a extension method which will give me a specific field, e.g. `Field<T>("Foo")` but what I really need is the ability to say sum all the fields ***except*** field X, Y and Z.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "the result".  Do you mean you want to sum up all columns in all rows and come up with a single number?  Do you want an enumerable that returns the sum of all columns in each row?  Do you want to simply exclude the columns from appearing in the Telerik control you've tagged this question with the name of?

Comment: @Robert - I'm looking for a sum of all columns in all rows exclusive of two columns (id and name).

Answer (score 3):

You can use more LINQ:

```
DataColumn[] unwantedColumns = { table.Column1, ... };

var sum = table.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>()
                       .Except(unwantedColumns)
                       .Select(c => row.Field<int>(c))
                       .Sum();
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can modify the columns a `DataRow` has. You can modify the columns of a `DataTable` though.

Comment: I believe you're right, however, I'm not looking to modify but query for values here.  Essentially I want all the values in the grid summed up for display in a grand total cell, exclusive of two specific columns (id and name).